# SSRS 2008: How to define Table/Tablix style without using a wizard?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Or how do I change the Table (Tablix) style in an already existing Report Server Project?

(I'm talking about a style which can be set in Report Server Project Wizard)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The style selected as a step in the Report wizard sets many properties on individual items in the report. Once created there is no easy way to switch a report from one style to another.

Two options:

1. Recreate the report using the wizard and select the new style.
2. Create two reports using a simple dataset, and then compare the resulting .rdl file (XML) in a file compare utility, such as UltraCompare. This will give you a list of all the different properties.

The file used for the style templates is at
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Business Intelligence Wizards\Reports\Styles\en\StyleTemplates.xml` in my installation of BIDS.

Examining this file can show you the changed properties as well.